# CSS child selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two labels within a li amd i want to style second label, is there a way to target the second label. It has to work on IE7

I wrote like this

```
         <ul>
          <li>
             <label for="asi plan status">A&SI Accountable VP:</label>
             <label>Tye Schriever</label>
           </li>
            </ul>

ul li label label{color:red}
```

Any other way..?

Comment: The CSS3 way would be: `ul li label+label`, but I'm not sure if IE7 supports this.

Comment: Adjacent sibling? That's CSS 2.1, I think, not 3. And [IE has problems up to, and including, version 8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t12).

Comment: @Exelian @David Thomas: AFAIK IE7/IE8 only have parsing problems with it in very specific situations. `ul li label+label` should work correctly. And yes `+` is a CSS2.1 selector. Just because it's not syntax you see every day, or you think it has poor IE support, does not make it a brand new CSS3 feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use css2 `:first-child` property define your properties for second label in common & through `first-child` you can override the css property for first `label` like this:

```
label{color:red}
label:first-child{color:yellow}
```

it's supported by `IE7` also but approach is different.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to target the second label and nothing else, you can use

```
ul li label + label
```

No need for overrides or CSS3's `:last-child` or adding classes to work around IE, etc. Although the comments mention IE7 and IE8 having problems with the `+` selector, it should work properly in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`:last-child`-selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild), but that isn't supported by Internet Explorer.

```
li label:last-child { color:red }
```

**Assign a class-attribute to the label** instead, to get it properly working on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have mentioned, there are legitimate CSS selectors to achieve what you want, but IE7 doesn't support those selectors.

When I need to patch support for `:last-child` in IE7, I use this technique with jQuery:

```
$('li label:last-child').addClass('last-child');
```

And then in my CSS I can use use

```
li label.last-child {
  /* some styles here */
}
```

So we leverage jQuery excellent CSS selector support to apply a class to the elements you want to style, and then style them in the CSS>

Comment: If `:last-child` is anything that doesn't require a long chain of `+` selectors to reach, use `+` instead for free IE7 support.

Comment: Quite right, this is just a more universal solution for using `:last-child` with IE7.